# Regular expression to replace "escaped" characters with their originals

Tags: python, regex, parsing, markup

NOTE: **I'm not parsing lots of or html or generic html with regex. I know that's bad**

**TL;DR**:

I have strings like

```
A sentence with an exclamation\! Next is a \* character
```

Where there are "escaped" characters in the original markup. I wish to replace them with their "originals". And get:

```
A sentence with an exclamation! Next is a * character
```

---

I have a small bit data that I need to extract from some wiki markup.

I'm only dealing with paragraphs/snippets here, so I don't need a big robust solution. In python, I tried a test:

```
s = "test \\* \\! test * !! **"

r = re.compile("""\\.""") # Slash followed by anything

r.sub("-", s)
```

This SHOULD yeild:

```
test - - test * !! **
```

But it doesn't do anything. Am I missing something here?

Furthermore, I'm not sure how to go about replacing any given escaped character with its original, so I would probably just make a list and sub with specific regexes like:

```
\\\*
```

and

```
\\!
```

There's probably a much cleaner way to do this, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing something, namely the `r` prefix:

```
r = re.compile(r"\\.") # Slash followed by anything
```

Both python and `re` attach meaning to `\`; your doubled backslash becomes just one backslash when you pass the string value to `re.compile()`, by which time `re` sees `\.`, meaning a literal full stop.:

```
>>> print """\\."""
\.
```

By using `r''` you tell python not to interpret escape codes, so now `re` is given a string with `\\.`, meaning a literal backslash followed by any character:

```
>>> print r"""\\."""
\\.
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "test \\* \\! test * !! **"
>>> r = re.compile(r"\\.") # Slash followed by anything
>>> r.sub("-", s)
'test - - test * !! **'
```

The rule of thumb is: when defining regular expressions, use `r''` raw string literals, saving you to have to double-escape everything that has meaning to both Python and regular expression syntax.

Next, you want to replace the 'escaped' character; use groups for that, `re.sub()` lets you reference groups as the replacement value:

```
r = re.compile(r"\\(.)") # Note the parethesis, that's a capturing group
r.sub(r'\1', s)          # \1 means: replace with value of first capturing group
```

Now the output is:

```
>>> r = re.compile(r"\\(.)") # Note the parethesis, that's a capturing group
>>> r.sub(r'\1', s) 
'test * ! test * !! **'
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear and concise response. I was under the impression that triple-quoting in python meant to take the string literally (as in ... as literally as possible). Don't know why, but now I know that's what the r prefix does. Thanks!

Comment: Triple-quoting makes it easy to include newlines and single quotes without escaping; you can combine raw and triple quoting too. :-)