# Python - Should I be using string prefix r when looking for a period (full stop or .) using regex?

Tags: python, regex, string

I would like to know the reason I get the same result when using string prefix "r" or not when looking for a period (full stop) using python regex.

After reading a number sources (Links below) a multiple times and experimenting with in code to find the same result (again see below), I am still unsure of:

1. What is the difference when using string prefix "r" and not using string prefix "r", when looking for a period using regex?
2. Which way is considered the correct way of finding a period in a string using python regex with string prefix "r" or without string prefix "r"?

---

```
re.compile("\.").sub("!", "blah.")
```

'blah!'

```
re.compile(r"\.").sub("!", "blah.")
```

'blah!'

```
re.compile(r"\.").search("blah.").group()
```

'.'

```
re.compile("\.").search("blah.").group()
```

'.'

Sources I have looked at:

Python docs: string literals
http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

[Regular expression to replace "escaped" characters with their originals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866339/regular-expression-to-replace-escaped-characters-with-their-originals)

[Python regex - r prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241600/python-regex-r-prefix)

r prefix is for raw strings
http://forums.udacity.com/questions/7000217/r-prefix-is-for-raw-strings

Comment: This should be a duplicate of [Python regex - r prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241600/python-regex-r-prefix) but I am out of close votes for today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The raw string notation is just that, a notation to specify a string value. The notation results in different string values when it comes to backslash escapes recognized by the normal string notation. Because regular expressions *also* attach meaning to the backslash character, raw string notation is quite handy as it avoids having to use excessive escaping.

Quoting from the [Python Regular Expression HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague):

> The solution is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular expressions; backslashes are not handled in any special way in a string literal prefixed with `'r'`, so `r"\n"` is a two-character string containing `'\'` and `'n'`, while `"\n"` is a one-character string containing a newline. Regular expressions will often be written in Python code using this raw string notation.

The `\.` combination has no special meaning in regular python strings, so there is no difference, *at all* between the result of `'\.'` and `r'\.'`; you can use either:

```
>>> len('\.')
2
>>> len(r'\.')
2
```

Raw strings only make a difference when the backslash + other characters do have special meaning in regular string notation:

```
>>> '\b'
'\x08'
>>> r'\b'
'\\b'
>>> len('\b')
1
>>> len(r'\b')
2
```

The `\b` combination has special meaning; in a regular string it is interpreted as the backspace character. But regular expressions see `\b` as a word boundary anchor, so you'd have to use `\\b` in your Python string every time you wanted to use this in a regular expression. Using `r'\b'` instead makes it much easier to read and write your expressions.

The regular expression functions are passed string *values*; the *result* of Python interpreting your string literal. The functions do not know if you used raw or normal string literal syntax.